# Stop extra intervals

Tags: javascript, html

I've read around but still do not understand how to stop this.

My program is very simple. When i press start, 3 random numbers will appear every 1 second. However, whenever i press start multiple times, setInterval() will run multiple times as well.

How do i ensure that whenever i press start again, only one setInterval() is running.  I tried to add a clearInterval method before my setInterval method but to no avail.

```js
function start() {
  document.getElementById("number1").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("number2").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("number3").disabled = false;
  chosennumber = prompt("choose a number between 0 to 9");
  scorenum2 = 0;
  
  if (/^([1-9])$/.test(chosennumber) == false || chosennumber.trim() == "") {
    alert("Enter only intergers 1 to 9");
  } else {

    document.getElementById("chosennum").innerHTML = chosennumber;
    document.getElementById("scorenum").innerHTML = scorenum2;

    interval = setInterval(start2, 1000);
  }
}

function start2() {
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

  document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = rand;
  document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = rand2;
  document.getElementById("number3").innerHTML = rand3;
}
```

```css
#number1 {
  float: left;
  color: red;
  font-size: 200px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

#number2 {
  float: left;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 200px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

#number3 {
  float: left;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 200px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

#chosennum {
  color: green;
}

#scorenum {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Start Game" onClick="start()">

<br>
<br>
<div id="">
  <h1>Your chosen number is: <span id="chosennum"> </span></h1>
  <h1>Your score so far: <span id="scorenum"> </span></h1>
</div>

<div id=""></div>

<button id="number1"></button>
<button id="number2" ></button>
<button id="number3"></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a boolean to ensure that there is just one interval running.

```js
var interval = false;
function start() {
  document.getElementById("number1").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("number2").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("number3").disabled = false;
  chosennumber = prompt("choose a number between 0 to 9");
  scorenum2 = 0;
  
  if (/^([1-9])$/.test(chosennumber) == false || chosennumber.trim() == "") {
    alert("Enter only intergers 1 to 9");
  } else {

    document.getElementById("chosennum").innerHTML = chosennumber;
    document.getElementById("scorenum").innerHTML = scorenum2;

    if(interval === false) {
        interval = setInterval(start2, 1000);
    }
  }
}

function start2() {
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

  document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = rand;
  document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = rand2;
  document.getElementById("number3").innerHTML = rand3;
}
```

```css
#number1 {
  float: left;
  color: red;
  font-size: 200px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

#number2 {
  float: left;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 200px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

#number3 {
  float: left;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 200px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

#chosennum {
  color: green;
}

#scorenum {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Start Game" onClick="start()">

<br>
<br>
<div id="">
  <h1>Your chosen number is: <span id="chosennum"> </span></h1>
  <h1>Your score so far: <span id="scorenum"> </span></h1>
</div>

<div id=""></div>

<button id="number1"></button>
<button id="number2" ></button>
<button id="number3"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just track the `id` returned by the `setInterval` function, if the id is there don't invoke it again.

```js
const start = (function(){
 let id;
 function start() {
  document.getElementById("number1").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("number2").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("number3").disabled = false;
  chosennumber = prompt("choose a number between 0 to 9");
  scorenum2 = 0;
  
  if (/^([1-9])$/.test(chosennumber) == false || chosennumber.trim() == "") {
    alert("Enter only intergers 1 to 9");
  } else {

    document.getElementById("chosennum").innerHTML = chosennumber;
    document.getElementById("scorenum").innerHTML = scorenum2;

    if(!id){
    id = setInterval(start2, 1000);
    }
    
  }
}

function start2() {
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

  document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = rand;
  document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = rand2;
  document.getElementById("number3").innerHTML = rand3;
}
return start;
})();
```

```css
#number1 {
  float: left;
  color: red;
  font-size: 200px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

#number2 {
  float: left;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 200px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

#number3 {
  float: left;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 200px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

#chosennum {
  color: green;
}

#scorenum {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Start Game" onClick="start()">

<br>
<br>
<div id="">
  <h1>Your chosen number is: <span id="chosennum"> </span></h1>
  <h1>Your score so far: <span id="scorenum"> </span></h1>
</div>

<div id=""></div>

<button id="number1"></button>
<button id="number2" ></button>
<button id="number3"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just set one global vaiable name clear_interval
first you should set

```
clear_inteval = true
```

and then....

```
if(clear_interval)
{
    interval = setInterval(start2, 1000);
    clear_interval = false
}
```

And your problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to add different intervals in the future using the same interval variable, you can `clearInterval(intervalVariable)` before you assign the new interval. 
If you're sure that the intervals are just one interval being created over and over, you can also use the same method or set a flag to check for the interval before creating a new one.